# Unable to install openjdk-7-jre-headless package

Tags: java, ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to install Jenkins on my guest OS (ubuntu 14.04) provisioned through Vagrant (precise64 box).

I have downloaded the Jenkins package and I have installed `default-jdk` package and i am trying to install `openjdk-7-jre-headless` package.
When i give this command

```
apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

I am getting this error:

```
openjdk-7-jre-headless : Depends: libsctp1 (>= 1.0.10+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Kindly Help me.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you run `apt-get update` before?

Comment: Yes. I have even tried using `apt-get -f install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless`

Comment: Why should he do that?

Answer (score 0):

The following `Vagrantfile` works for me flawlessly:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
  SHELL    
end
```

So you seem to have messed up something manually.

Comment: Guess I have to start from the scratch! Thanks anyways. I will make sure to carefully configure the Vagrant File next time.